# R shiny insert a column to tibble based on input

Tags: r, shiny

I have a simple tibble with 2 columns, `Column1` and `Column2`. And I want to add a third column `Column3` if the input from selectInput `s1` is `No`, but there should only be 2 columns if the input from selectInput `s1` is `Yes`.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("s1", label = "Select", choices = c("Yes","No")),
  dataTableOutput("table1")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  df = reactive({
    tibble(Column1 = rep(1,10), Column2 = rep(2,10))
  })
  
  output$table1 = renderDataTable({
    df()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: And what is the difficulty you encounter? Use a `if/else` in your reactive conductor, based on the condition `input$s1 == "Yes"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Stéphane Laurent's suggestion, I have tried to come up with an answer, please correct it if there's something fundamentally wrong.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("s1", label = "Select", choices = c("Yes","No")),
  dataTableOutput("table1")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  df = reactive({
    tibble(Column1 = rep(1,10), Column2 = rep(2,10))
  })
  
  s2 = reactive({add_column(df(),Column3=1)})
  
  output$table1 = renderDataTable({
    if(input$s1=="Yes"){
      df()
    } else {s2()}
  })
  

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```